# Is there a specific reason to choose $3$ and $1$ for evaluating these limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm reading Gemignami's *Calculus and Statistics*.

There are two examples of limits that left me confused:

> **Example 5.** Let $f$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2$. We now evaluate
>
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\color{red}{3}+h)-f(\color{red}{3})}{h}$$

And:

> **Example 6.** Let $f$ be defined by $f(x)=x^{1/2}$, where $x$ is any nonnegative number. We shall evaluate
>
> $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(\color{red}{1}+h)-f(\color{red}{1})}{h}=\frac{(\color{red}{1}+h)^{1/2}-\color{red}{1}}{h}$$

I don't understand why he chose $\color{red}{3}$ and $\color{red}{1}$ for these examples, the second example brings the "*where $x$ is any nonnegative number.*" I'm not sure if I could choose any nonnegative number or if he chose $3$ and $1$ for some specific reason. The text also doesn't point specificaly if there is a reason for doing so (or I'm not seeing the reason).

Comment: Arbitrary choices to have concrete points for the example computations. For the second, $x \geqslant 0$ is necessary since the square root is not defined for negative arguments (we're being real here, not complex).

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes. In the second case I know why $x \geqslant 0$ is chosen. But I'm thinking that it could be any $x \geqslant 0$. Is there an specific reason for chosing $1$ instead of, say, $5$?

Comment: No, as I said the choices for the points for the example computations are arbitrary. Well, for the square root, choosing $1$ gives a very slightly simpler computation possibly.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes. Then it was similar to what I was thinking. But I'm a little afraid of assuming *obvious* things in mathematics since I discovered that $0!=1$, for me it was *obvious* it was $0!=0$.

Comment: Being wary of assuming obvious things is good, some "obvious" things are indeed false. Concerning $0! = 1$, that is on the other hand obvious if you look at it as $n! = \prod\limits_{k\in \{m \in \mathbb{N}\colon 1 \leqslant m \leqslant n\}} k$, since $\prod\limits_{k \in \varnothing} A(k) = 1$ whatever $A$ is. (What seems obvious depends on from where you look.)

Comment: @GustavoBandeira $0!=1$ is just a comfortable definition. Notice that the basic definition $n!=1\times 2\times\ldots\times n$ doesn't really make sense for $n=0$. So, you need to define $0!$ separately. You could define it as $0$ if you want. The only thing is that some formulas will look different.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira: Care must be taken when $x=0$ in the second example. In this case, we can only calculate the one-sided limit as $h\to0^+$ since you aren't considering the square root of negative numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both of these,
I think the goal is to
allow you to compare the results
of the $formulas$ for the derivatives
($2x$ for $x^2$ and $1/(2\sqrt{x})$
for $x^{1/2}$)
with the results of working out the limits.

For the $x^2$ case,

$\begin{align}
\dfrac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}
&=\dfrac{(3+h)^2-(3)^2}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{(9+6h+h^2)-9}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{6h+h^2}{h}\\
&=6+h\\
\end{align}
$,

and the limit of this as $h \to 0$ is $6$,
which is also $2x$ evaluated at $x = 3$
(as it should be, of course).

For the $\sqrt{x}$ case,
$\dfrac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}
=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h}-\sqrt{1}}{h}
=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{h}
$.

Here, since it is not immediately obvious
how
$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{h}$
behaves as $h \to 0$,
you have to apply some ingenuity
and use
this result
(which you should understand and memorize
for your future work with square roots):

$\begin{align}
\sqrt{a^2+b}-a
&=(\sqrt{a^2+b}-a)\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2+b}+a}{\sqrt{a^2+b}+a}\\
&=\dfrac{(\sqrt{a^2+b}+a)(\sqrt{a^2+b}-a)}{\sqrt{a^2+b}+a}\\
&=\dfrac{(a^2+b)-a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b}+a}\\
&=\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b}+a}\\
\end{align}
$

Setting $a=1$ and $b=h$,
$(\sqrt{1+h}-1)
= \dfrac{h}{\sqrt{1+h}+1}
$
so
$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{h}
=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+h}+1}
$.

Since $\sqrt{1+h}$ clearly goes to $1$
as $h \to 0$,
$\sqrt{1+h}+1 \to 2$ as $h \to 0$,
so
$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{h}
\to \dfrac{1}{2}$.